# Replace integer value via regular expression with python

Tags: python, regex

Well,
I am trying to apply some regular expression(search/replace) on xml. Yes I have to use some lib.'s but in that case I cannot. My problem is ,as you may figure out, replacing value of node with an integer. When I try that, it gives me grouping error.Here are my patterns:

search pattern:

```
(<fieldset>)([^>].+)(<ipadd>)([^>].+)(<value>)([^>].+)(</value>)([^>].+)(</ipadd>)([^>].+)(</fieldset>)
```

replace pattern:

```
\1\2\3\4\5123.123.123.123\7\8\9\10\11
```

As you see fifth group becomes "\5123" in replace pattern. And of course it doesn't work.

Well if I use something like this:

```
\1\2\3\4\5 123.123.123.123\7\8\9\10\11
```

It works. But I don't want a space or something else there.

And it also work with string:

```
\1\2\3\4\5foofoofoo\7\8\9\10\11
```

ah I am using re.sub() for replacing.

Is there a way that I can use it without spaces?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Python Regular Expression operations - re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

> In addition to character escapes and
>   backreferences as described above,
>   `\g<name>` will use the substring
>   matched by the group named name, as
>   defined by the `(?P<name>...)` syntax.
>   `\g<number>` uses the corresponding
>   group number; `\g<2>` is therefore
>   equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous
>   in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20`
>   would be interpreted as a reference to
>   group 20, not a reference to group 2
>   followed by the literal character '0'.
>   The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in
>   the entire substring matched by the
>   RE.